# Is there a constant which defines the max value of long or integer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, ipad

In java, there is a constant for the max value of Long.
Such as:

```
long minBillId = Long.MAX_VALUE
```

Is there a constant for the max value of long or int in Obj-C?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you import `limits.h` 
you can call `LONG_MAX`

For reference this [site](http://reference.jumpingmonkey.org/programming_languages/objective-c/types.html) shows how to get the max for all types as such:

```
#import <limits.h>
 // ...
NSLog(@"CHAR_MIN:   %c",   CHAR_MIN);
NSLog(@"CHAR_MAX:   %c",   CHAR_MAX);
NSLog(@"SHRT_MIN:   %hi",  SHRT_MIN);    // signed short int  
NSLog(@"SHRT_MAX:   %hi",  SHRT_MAX);
NSLog(@"INT_MIN:    %i",   INT_MIN);
NSLog(@"INT_MAX:    %i",   INT_MAX);
NSLog(@"LONG_MIN:   %li",  LONG_MIN);    // signed long int
NSLog(@"LONG_MAX:   %li",  LONG_MAX);
NSLog(@"ULONG_MIN not defined, it's always zero: %lu", 0);  
NSLog(@"ULONG_MAX:  %lu",  ULONG_MAX);   // unsigned long int
NSLog(@"LLONG_MIN:  %lli", LLONG_MIN);   // signed long long int
NSLog(@"LLONG_MAX:  %lli", LLONG_MAX);
NSLog(@"ULLONG_MIN not defined, it's always zero: %llu", 0);  
NSLog(@"ULLONG_MAX: %llu", ULLONG_MAX);  // unsigned long long int
```

Answer (score 12):

INT_MAX should resolve to 2147483647

This:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSInteger foo = INT_MAX;
    NSLog(@"foo: %li", foo);  // li because 64 bit OSX cmd line app

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
2012-03-18 13:58:54.509 Craplet[51324:707] foo: 2147483647
```

Comment: Should? Or does, always, because the language spec says so?

Answer (score 3):

```
  NSLog(@"INT_MIN:    %i",   INT_MIN);
  NSLog(@"INT_MAX:    %i",   INT_MAX);
  NSLog(@"LONG_MIN:   %li",  LONG_MIN); 
  NSLog(@"LONG_MAX:   %li",  LONG_MAX);
```